# IBM Cloud Code Engine fails to build for private repo

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I'm using [IBM Cloud Code Engine to build the source code from a private git repo](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-application-workloads#deploy-app-source-code). I have tried many times, and the buildrun always failed. Following are the steps I have done.

1. Add my public key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to my private repo as a deploy key
2. Use IBM Cloud Code Engine CLI to create repo access credential
   `ibmcloud ce repo create --name ibmgithub --key-path /root/.ssh/id_rsa --host github.ibm.com`
3. Use IBM Cloud Code Engine CLI to create a build and then submit a build run
   `ibmcloud ce build create --name minion --image us.icr.io/mynamespace/myimg --rs ce-default-icr-us-south  --git-repo-secret ibmgithub  --source https://github.ibm.com/myaccount/myrepo --strategy dockerfile --size medium`
4. The build run always fails

```
#:~/synthetics-private-minion# ibmcloud ce bd get -n minion
Getting build 'minion'
OK
Name:          minion  
ID:            0abc63a0-07d5-42c5-b70a-227e52310276  
Project Name:  private location  
Project ID:    25491342-e9e8-4ac7-90ff-b9994cda9242  
Age:           6m24s  
Created:       2021-03-31T04:11:41-05:00  
Status:        Succeeded  
Reason:        all validations succeeded  
Image:            us.icr.io/mynamespace/myimg 
Registry Secret:  ce-default-icr-us-south  
Build Strategy:   kaniko-medium  
Timeout:          10m0s  
Source:           https://github.ibm.com/myaccount/myrepo  
Commit:           main  
Dockerfile:       Dockerfile  
Repo Secret:      ibmgithub  
Build Runs:    
  Name              Status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            Age  
  minion-run-sj5fl  "step-git-source-source-cm7pc" exited with code 1 (image: "icr.io/obs/codeengine/tekton-pipeline/git-init-4874978a9786b6625dd8b6ef2a21aa70@sha256:47b8008fa1910fa36c8284871eb9d8e7fbab8bc3a1db4cdd97c61d88727cc58f"); for logs run: kubectl -n 7pztl5cw3ad logs minion-run-sj5fl-nbzft-pod-rx9x9 -c step-git-source-source-cm7pc  5m42s
```

5. I doubt the build run failed to fetch the source code from my private repo. And I checked on the repo UI, it shows the deploy key `Never used`.

Can anyone shed some light on it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an ssh key, make sure the URL to your git repo starts with `git@` instead of `https://`. So it should be **git@github.ibm.com/myaccount/myrepo** in your case.

For further issues with failing builds, you can check the related [troubleshooting buildruns section in the Code Engine docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-troubleshoot-build#ts-build-gitsource-stepfail).

Answer (score 2):

The build capability of IBM Cloud Code Engine can access source code in public and private repositories. There are two criteria for a repository to be public:

1. The repository must be marked as public at your repository provider (for example GitHub, or GitLab).
2. The repository must be accessible without any authentication. This plays a role for GitHub Enterprise installations, for example github.ibm.com, which can put an additional authentication in front to prevent anonymous access.

The second criteria makes your repository a private one from Code Engine perspective. To address a repository in a Code Engine build, there is a simple rule:

- For a public repository, use the HTTPS URL of the repository and no repository access secret
- For a private repository, use the SSH URL of the repository and a repository access secret

You correctly specify a repository access secret, but must change your source URL to use the SSH protocol. The easiest way to find the URL, is the Code drop-down in GitHub:

[image: GitHub Code drop-down]

So it should be **git@github.ibm.com/myaccount/myrepo** in your case.

Further references:

Instructions on how to setup a repository access secret can be found in [Accessing private code repositories](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-code-repositories).

Troubleshooting for a failed BuildRun can be found in [Troubleshooting tips for builds](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-troubleshoot-build). It includes instructions to retrieve the logs from your BuildRun and translates the error message you see into the root cause with steps to resolve them.

Comment: Thanks Sascha. After I change the source format to git. It's working now.